# Using a data_frame as an argument into a mutate and group_by routine

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data_frame (db) here with lots of columns:

```
A  B   C   D ...      ZZ
1  .23 .21   ...      .23
2  .45 .12   ...      .23
1  .47  ...          .53
2  .49  ...          .27
```

I want to employ group_by and mutate with a function which gets a complete data_frame and returns a vector.

```
function1 <- function(data_frame) {
    ...
    return(vector)
}
db %>%
    group_by(A) %>%
    mutate(results = function1(.))
```

This is not working. It returns the results of using the function with the whole data_frame, not with the groups.

I know I could solve it using for, but I'm looking for a dplyr solution. The function necessarily gets a data_frame, I'm not passing columns separately as arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `dplyr`

My trick has been to use `bind_cols`. By itself it won't honor any groups, so you need to nest it within a `do` block, such as:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    do(bind_cols(., {
        # "insert complex stuff here"
        data_frame(results = apply(., 1, mean))
    }))
# Source: local data frame [32 x 12]
# Groups: cyl [3]
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb  results
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1   22.8     4 108.0    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1 23.59818
# 2   24.4     4 146.7    62  3.69 3.190 20.00     1     0     4     2 24.63455
# 3   22.8     4 140.8    95  3.92 3.150 22.90     1     0     4     2 27.23364
# # ... with 29 more rows
```

On benefit of this approach is that the code in the block can return ***one or more*** columns without further complication.

So, using your code, it would look something like:

```
db %>%
    group_by(A) %>%
    do(bind_cols(., data_frame(results = function(.))))
```

### `tidyr`

Another option is to use [`tidy`](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr) (RStudio blog [here](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/02/02/tidyr-0-4-0/), though a little out of date it is still useful).

```
library(tidyr) # nest, unnest
library(purrr) # map
mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(results = map(data, ~ apply(., 1, mean))) %>%
    unnest()
```

Your code might be something like (untested):

```
db %>%
    group_by(A) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(results = purrr::map(data, ~ function1(.))) %>%
    unnest()
```